# How to call a function from centre item only in ngx-owl-carousel?

Tags: angular, typescript, owl-carousel

I have a function that needs to be called only when the element is in centre of slider. How can I achieve this?

My HTML is:

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slides">
        <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="slide.id">
            <img [src]="slide.img" (swipeup)="startAnimation('swipeup',$event)">
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>

</owl-carousel-o>
```

My customOptions is:

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: false,
    center: true,
    dots: false,
    nav: false,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 3
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      },
      740: {
        items: 3
      },
      940: {
        items: 4
      }
    }
  }
```

The function `startAnimation()` needs to be called only if the image is in center.

I'm fairly new in Angular. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a guard so that if the index of your element is not equal to `slides.length`s middle element, it won't execute the rest

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index"> <!-- get index here -->
   <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="slide.id">
       <img [src]="slide.img" (swipeup)="startAnimation('swipeup',$event, i, slides.length)"> <!-- pass index and length here -->
   </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

```js
startAnimation('swipeup',$event, index, slidesLength) { 
  if(index !== (Math.floor((slidesLength- 1) / 2))) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, what if instead of calling a function I want to give it a custom style on it? I am facing a problem that I can't style it's child generated components, and opened a question for it... But have no idea how to get around. ChatGPT is only said weird stuff haha